"Shrinking" a dense open set into a manifold
Question. Let $M \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be a compact smoothly embedded $k$-manifold. Does there exist a set $U_M \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and a surjective function $\varphi_M: U_M \rightarrow M$ such that (1) $U_M$ is dense in $\mathbb R^n$ and (2) $\varphi_M$ is continuous on every compact subset of $U_M$?
Example. The above holds for $M$ given by a product of spheres, because $x \mapsto x/\|x\|$ maps $\mathbb R^n \backslash \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb S^{n-1}$. In particular, $M$ can be a torus.
Other concrete examples that would be a good starting point include the real and complex projective spaces.
